# noEclipse Juno - No java virtual machine has been found

Tags: android, eclipse, eclipse-juno

I've just reinstalled Win7 on my PC so my java got deleted. 
But I've backed up my eclipse and then put it back.
I installed JDK again but there's an error when I try to open Eclipse.
I also put directory of java, just see my .ini file

```
-startup
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.0.v20120522-1813.jar
--launcher.library
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.win32.win32.x86_1.1.200.v20120913-144807
-product
org.eclipse.epp.package.java.product
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
256M
-showsplash
org.eclipse.platform
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
256m
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
-vm
 C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_25\bin\javaw.exe
-vmargs 
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.5
 -Dhelp.lucene.tokenizer=standard
 -Xms40m
 -Xmx512m
```

That's eclipse juno and it drops error code 13. Please help me, I was searching for some error fixes on stackoverflow but nothing helpfull

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Error 13 is usually a 32/64-bit mismatch.  If you're on 64-bit Windows, the fact that Java isn't under the "c:\Program Files (x86)" directory means it's also 64-bit, and you clearly have a 32-bit Eclipse.  Try the 64-bit version of Eclipse.